Circuitry for change LCD to 7-segment
My boss bought a TEMP/HUM sensor with LCD display ( just display the digits ). And he asks me to modify product from LCD to 7-segment or LED. Preliminary checking, the original LCD has 4 com and 12 segment. I would like to know how to change those com/segment signal to light on the LED/7-segment?

what is driving the LCD?

LCD displays use multi level bipolar signals to ensure that no net DC voltage is applied across the display segments

As it is die bonding, so I estimate it is the MCU JXH400K with 1/3bias and 1/4 duty

You want to design a new product or make one piece with an LED display?

make a one piece with an LED display ( using 7-segment or using LED to build digits )

Many years ago I had a similar task, with no option to change the device. But in my case the LCD was not multiplexed, so I could synchronize on the single COM and read all the segments. Simple CMOS digital inputs were sufficient to drive the logic. Unfortunately this is not possible for you, as you need to take analog voltages into account.

The easiest and by far most cost-effective thing would be to buy a unit with the display you need.
The next easiest thing is to buy a calibrated digital-output temperature-humidity sensor and combine with a suitable MCU to drive an LED display (either directly, or with an LED driver chip, depending on your requirements).
Trying to decode the LCD segment drives in real time would not be a trivial project. Not impossible, but a bit silly. Imagine sampling each of the 16 lines with an ADC at a few kHz and calculating the AC (preferably RMS) voltage across each of the 48 segment positions (or however many are actually used). Add some code to deal with false readings during changes in the display. Should be possible with something like an STM32F411.

How to interface between those LCD segment and the 48 segment? In HW point of view, any circuitry that can be suggested?

You could buffer all 16 lines with 16 RRIO op-amps (just 4x quad op-amps connected as voltage followers) and feed them to ADC inputs and do the rest in firmware. You will probably need another input for the battery voltage unless you replace the battery with a regulated voltage.  Very little hardware.

I have tried to build one digit using 4 pcs LM324 ( one 7-segment LED need 7 op-amp for differential of com/seg and then 7 op-amp for comparator of each differential output ).  Finally it can display the digit. But it is flashing due to the signal enter to the 7-segment LED is something like 1/5 duty cycle. So I would like to know how to fix the  flashing problem, Thanks!

Calculate the RMS voltage across each segment to start with, and compare against a threshold.

Finally I fix it by using RC circuitry.
